# Faster algorithm to check the colors in a image

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Supposing I am given an image of 2048x2048 and i want to know the total number of colors present in the image, what is the fastest possible algorithm? I came up with two algorithm but they are slow.

Algorithm 1:

- Compare the current pixel an the next pixel and if they are different
- Check a temporary variable, which contains all the detected colors, to see if the color is present or not
- If not present add it to the array(List) and increment noOfColors.

This Algorithm works but is slow. For a 1600x1200 pixels image it takes around 3 sec.

Algorithm 2:
The obvious method of checking the each pixel with all other pixels and recording the no of occurences of the color and incrementing the count. This is very very slow, almost like a hung app. So is there any better approach? I need all the pixel info.

Comment: One optimization would probably be to use `set` instead of `list`.

Comment: You could try a hash table to increase the speed of adding/comparing colors. The `set` or `unordered_set` can help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DRAM is dirt cheap. Use brute force. Fill a tab, count.

On a core2duo @ 3.0GHz :

0.35secs for 4096x4096  32 bits rgb

0.20secs after some trivial parallelization (I do know nothing of omp)

However, if you are to use 64bit rgb (one channel = 16 bits) it is another question (not enough memory).
You shall probably need a good hash table function.
Using random pixels, same size takes 10 secs.

Remark: at 0.15 secs, the std::bitset<> solution is faster (it gets slower trivially parallelized !).

Solution, c++11

```
    #include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

#define  _16M 256*256*256

typedef union {
    struct { unsigned char r,g,b,n ; } r_g_b_n ;
    unsigned char rgb[4] ;
    unsigned i_rgb;
} RGB ;

RGB make_RGB(unsigned char r, unsigned char g , unsigned char b) {
    RGB res; 
    res.r_g_b_n.r = r; 
    res.r_g_b_n.g = g;
    res.r_g_b_n.b = b;
    res.r_g_b_n.n = 0;
    return res;
}

static_assert(sizeof(RGB)==4,"bad RGB size not 4");
static_assert(sizeof(unsigned)==4,"bad i_RGB size not 4");

struct Image 
{ 
  Image (unsigned M, unsigned N) : M_(M) , N_(N) , v_(M*N) {}
  const RGB* tab() const {return & v_[0] ; }
  RGB* tab() {return & v_[0] ; }
  unsigned M_ , N_;
  std::vector<RGB> v_;
};

void FillRandom(Image & im) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> rnd(0,_16M-1);
    std::mt19937 rng;
    const int N = im.M_ * im.N_;
    RGB* tab = im.tab();
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        unsigned r = rnd(rng) ;
        *tab++ = make_RGB(  (r & 0xFF) , (r>>8 & 0xFF), (r>>16 & 0xFF) ) ;
    }
}

size_t Count(const Image & im) {
const int N = im.M_ * im.N_;
std::vector<char> count(_16M,0);
const RGB* tab = im.tab();
#pragma omp parallel 
{
#pragma omp for 
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    count[ tab->i_rgb ] = 1 ;
    tab++;
    }
}
size_t nColors = 0 ;
#pragma omp parallel 
{
#pragma omp for 
for (int i = 0 ; i<_16M; i++) nColors += count[i];
}
return nColors;
}

int main() {
    Image im(4096,4096);
    FillRandom(im);
    typedef boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock hrc;
    auto start = hrc::now();

    std::cout << " # colors " << Count(im) << std::endl ; 

    boost::chrono::duration<double> sec  = hrc::now() - start;
    std::cout << " took " << sec.count() << " seconds\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you explain the program a bit?

Comment: i dint understand the #pragma omp thingy. why cant i go for threads?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (or [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)), and simply do a single loop though the pixels, adding the colors to the set. Then the number of colors is the size of the set.

Comment: What is the complexity of this?

Comment: @PeterWood It's one loop through all pixels, so O(n).

Comment: But inserting into the `set` has what complexity?

Comment: @joachim: will it be faster if i call GetPixel from a bitmap ref or if i have the bitmap info in an array and read the array? which is better?

Comment: @Koushik If you _already_ have the pixels in an array, then that will probably be faster.

Comment: @PeterWood Check the links, it's documented in the methods.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `set::insert` is O(log(size)) and `unordered_set::insert` is average O(1), worst case O(size).

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is suited for parallelization. Split the image in several parts and execute the algorithm for each part in a separate task. To avoid syncing each should have its own storage for the unique colors. When all tasks are done, you aggregate the results.

Comment: When using a set as the storage, the size of the union of all sets would be the number of colours. So even aggregating is quite straightforward.

Comment: @marius bancila are you suggesting i use threads or this Parallel Patters library. this PPL, i found out about it now so will have to study that..

Comment: You can use (naked) threads, you can use tasks and PPL, or even AMP to run on the GPU, it's your choice. The point is that no sequential algorithm will perform better than a parallel version of it.

Comment: parallelization is not an algorithm. IMHO, suggesting parallelization is always the wrong answer..

Comment: I suppose you can argue on that.

Answer (score 1):

The only feasible algorithm here is building a sort of a histogram of the image colors. The only difference in your case is that instead of calculating the population of each color you need just to know if it's zero or not.

Depending on which color space you work, you may use either an `std::set` to tag existing colors (as Joachim Pileborg suggested), or just use something like `std::bitset`, which is obviously faster. This depends on how much distinct colors exist in your color-space.

Also, like Marius Bancila noted, this procedure is a perfect match for parallelization. Calculated the histogram-like data for image parts, and then merge it. Naturally the image division should be based on its memory partition, not the geometric properties. In simple words - split the image vertically (by batches of scan lines), not horizontally.

And, if possible, you should either use some low-level library/code to run through pixels, or try to write your own. At least you **must** obtain a pointer to scan line and run on its pixels in a batch, rather than doing something like `GetPixel` for each pixel.

Answer (score 1):

The point, here, is that the ideal representation of an image as 2D array of colors is not the one that happens the way the image is stored on memory (color components can be arranged in "planes", there could be "padding" etc. So getting the pixels using a `GetPixel`-like function may take time.

The question, then, may even be somehow meaningless if the image is not the result of a "vectorial draw": think to a photograph: between two nearby "greens" you find all the shade of green, so the colors -in this case- are no more no less the ones supported by the encoding of the image itself (2^24, or 256, or 16 or ...), so, unless you are interested on the color distribution (how differently used they are), just counting them makes very few sense.

A workaround can be:

1. Create an in-memory bitmap having pixel in a "single plane format"
2. Blit your image into that bitmap using BitBlt or similar (this let the OS to make pixel
   conversion from the GPU,if any)
3. Get the bitmap-bits (this lets you
   access the stored values)
4. Play your "counting algorithm" (whatever
   it is) onto those values.

Note that step 1 and 2 can be avoided if you already know that the image is already in planar format.

If you have a multicore system, step 4 can also be assigned to different threads, each working part of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) which allows you to set individual bits and has a [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count) function.

You have a bit for each colour, there are 256 values for each of RGB, so that's 256*256*256 bits (16,777,216 colours). The `bitset` will use a byte for every 8 bits so it will use 2MB.

Use the pixel colour as an index into the `bitset`:

```
bitset<256*256*256> colours;

for(int pixel: pixels) {
    colours[pixel] = true;
}

colours.count();
```

This has linear complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Late comer to this answer, but could not help it since this algorithm is brutally fast, developed about 2 or more decades ago, when it really mattered.
3-D Lookup Table Color Matching
http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403257

Basically, it creates a 3d color loop up table and the search is very fast, I've done some modifications to suit my purpose for image binarization, so I reduced the color space from ff ff ff to f f f, and it's even 10 times faster. As it is right out of the box, I haven't found anything even close, including hash tables.

```
char * creatematcharray(struct rgb_color *palette, int palettesize)
    {
      int rval=16, gval=16, bval=16, len, r, g, b;
      char *taken, *match, *same;
      int i, set, sqstep, tp, maxtp, *entryr, *entryg, *entryb;
      char *table;

      len=rval*gval*bval;

      // Prepare table buffers:
      size_t size_of_table = len*sizeof(char);
      table=(char *)malloc(size_of_table);
      if (table==nullptr) return nullptr;

      // Select colors to use for fill:
      set=0;
      size_t size_of_taken = (palettesize * sizeof(int) * 3) +
          (palettesize*sizeof(char)) + (len * sizeof(char));
      taken=(char *)malloc(size_of_taken);
      same=taken + (len * sizeof(char));
      entryr=(int*)(same + (palettesize * sizeof(char)));
      entryg=entryr + palettesize;
      entryb=entryg + palettesize;
      if (taken==nullptr)
      {
        free((void *)table);
        return nullptr;
      }
      std::memset((void *)taken, 0, len * sizeof(char));
    //  std::cout << "sizes: " << size_of_table << " " << size_of_taken << std::endl;

      match=table;
      for (i=0; i<palettesize; i++)
      {
        same[i]=0;
        // Compute 3d-table coordinates of palette rgb color:
        r=palette[i].r&0x0f, g=palette[i].g&0x0f, b=palette[i].b&0x0f;
        // Put color in position:
        if (taken[b*rval*gval+g*rval+r]==0) set++;
        else same[match[b*rval*gval+g*rval+r]]=1;
        match[b*rval*gval+g*rval+r]=i;
        taken[b*rval*gval+g*rval+r]=1;
        entryr[i]=r; entryg[i]=g; entryb[i]=b;
      }

      // @@@ Fill match_array by steps: @@@
      for (set=len-set, sqstep=1; set>0; sqstep++)
      {
        for (i=0; i<palettesize && set>0; i++)
          if (same[i]==0)
          {
            // Fill all six sides of incremented cube (by pairs, 3 loops):
            for (b=entryb[i]-sqstep; b<=entryb[i]+sqstep; b+=sqstep*2)
              if (b>=0 && b<bval)
                for (r=entryr[i]-sqstep; r<=entryr[i]+sqstep; r++)
                  if (r>=0 && r<rval)
                  { // Draw one 3d line:
                    tp=b*rval*gval+(entryg[i]-sqstep)*rval+r;
                    maxtp=b*rval*gval+(entryg[i]+sqstep)*rval+r;
                    if (tp<b*rval*gval+0*rval+r)
                      tp=b*rval*gval+0*rval+r;
                    if (maxtp>b*rval*gval+(gval-1)*rval+r)
                      maxtp=b*rval*gval+(gval-1)*rval+r;
                    for (; tp<=maxtp; tp+=rval)
                      if (!taken[tp])
                        taken[tp]=1, match[tp]=i, set--;
                  }
            for (g=entryg[i]-sqstep; g<=entryg[i]+sqstep; g+=sqstep*2)
              if (g>=0 && g<gval)
                for (b=entryb[i]-sqstep; b<=entryb[i]+sqstep; b++)
                  if (b>=0 && b<bval)
                  { // Draw one 3d line:
                    tp=b*rval*gval+g*rval+(entryr[i]-sqstep);
                    maxtp=b*rval*gval+g*rval+(entryr[i]+sqstep);
                    if (tp<b*rval*gval+g*rval+0)
                      tp=b*rval*gval+g*rval+0;
                    if (maxtp>b*rval*gval+g*rval+(rval-1))
                      maxtp=b*rval*gval+g*rval+(rval-1);
                    for (; tp<=maxtp; tp++)
                      if (!taken[tp])
                        taken[tp]=1, match[tp]=i, set--;
                  }
            for (r=entryr[i]-sqstep; r<=entryr[i]+sqstep; r+=sqstep*2)
              if (r>=0 && r<rval)
                for (g=entryg[i]-sqstep; g<=entryg[i]+sqstep; g++)
                  if (g>=0 && g<gval)
                  { // Draw one 3d line:
                    tp=(entryb[i]-sqstep)*rval*gval+g*rval+r;
                    maxtp=(entryb[i]+sqstep)*rval*gval+g*rval+r;
                    if (tp<0*rval*gval+g*rval+r)
                      tp=0*rval*gval+g*rval+r;
                    if (maxtp>(bval-1)*rval*gval+g*rval+r)
                      maxtp=(bval-1)*rval*gval+g*rval+r;
                    for (; tp<=maxtp; tp+=rval*gval)
                      if (!taken[tp])
                        taken[tp]=1, match[tp]=i, set--;
                  }
          }
      }
      free((void *)taken);`enter code here`
      return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer: **unordered_map**

I use unordered_map, based on *my* testing.

> **You should test because your compiler / library may exhibit different performance** Comment out `#define USEHASH` to use map instead.

On my machine, the vanilla unordered_map (a hash implementation) is about twice as fast as map. Inasmuch as different compilers, libraries can vary enormously, you *must* test to see which is better. In production, I build a fake image on first start of the app, run both algorithms on it and time them, save an indication of which one is faster, and then preferentially use that for all subsequent starts on that the machine. It's nit-picky, but hey, the user's time is valuable to them.

For a DSLR image with 12,106,244 pixels (about 12 megapixels, not a typo) and 11,857,131 distinct colors (also not a typo), map takes about 14 seconds, while unordered map takes about 7 seconds:

**Test Code:**

```
#define USEHASH 1
#ifdef USEHASH
#include <unordered_map>
#endif

size = im->xw * im->yw;
#ifdef USEHASH
// unordered_map is about twice as fast as map on my mac with qt5
// --------------------------------------------------------------
#include <unordered_map>
    std::unordered_map<qint64, unsigned char> colors;
    colors.reserve(size); // pre-allocate the hash space
#else
    std::map<qint64, unsigned char> colors;
#endif
```

...use of either is in a loop where I build a 48-bit value of 0RGB in a 64-bit variable corresponding to the 16-bit RGB values of the image pixels, like so:

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    pel = BUILDPEL(i); // macro just shovels 0RGB into 64 bit pel from im
                       // You'd do the same for your image structure
                       // in whatever way is fastest for you
    colors[pel] = 1;
}
cc = colors.size();
// time here: 14 secs for map, 7 secs for unordered_map with
// 12,106,244 pixels containing 11,857,131 colors on 12/24 core,
// 3 GHz, 64GB machine.
```